# What's the smallest possible file size on disk?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find a solution to store a binary file in it's smallest size on disk. I'm reading vehicles VIN and plate number from a database that is 30 Bytes and when I put it in a txt file and save it, its size is 30B, but its size on disk is 4KB, which means if I save 100000 files or more, it would kill storage space.

So my question is that how can I write this 30B to an individual binary file to its smallest size on disk, and what is the smallest possible size of 30B on disk including other info such as file name and permissions?

Note: I do not want to save those text in database, just I want to make separate binary files.

Comment: The big question is - what file system are we talking about? And with answer to that, read up on said file system and you will have your answer.

Comment: This really depends on the filesystem you're using.

Comment: As the other comments said, this is very file system dependent. And 400MB is nothing these days, so why worry about it?

Comment: That is the minimum allocation unit for your filesystem - adding extra VINs will not make it any bigger till you need more than 4kB when it will take 8 kB on disk.

Comment: "*I do not want to save those text in database, just I want to make separate binary files.*" You have no choice. A "binary file" is an entry in a database. Filesystems are databases. It's just a question whether you pick a database that meets your needs or one that doesn't.

Comment: @Ross, its a question of efficiency. saving 400MB of data in 30B packets that take up 4K each is going to use up more than 50TB of hdd space!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

the smallest size of a file is always the cluster size of your disk, which is typically 4k. for data like this, having many records in a single file is really the only reasonable solution.

although another possibility would be to store those files in an archive, a zip file for example. under windows you can even access the zip contents pretty similar to ordinary files in explorer.

another creative possibility: store all the data *in the filename only*. a zero byte file takes only 1024 bytes in the MFT. (assuming NTFS)

edit: reading up on resident files, i found that on the newer 4k sector drives, the MFT entry is actually 4k, too. so it doesn't get smaller than this, whether the data size is 0 or not.

another edit: huge directories, with tens or hundreds of thousands of entries, will become quite unwieldy. don't try to open one in explorer, or be prepared to go drink a coffee while it loads.

Comment: This is not strictly true. NTFS, for example, supports "resident" files where the DATA stream can be stored inside the file's MFT record so files up to ~1000 bytes don't occupy any more clusters than an empty file would.

Comment: @AndrewMedico lol, AKA 'NTFS file descriptors are so large that a significant amount of space was left over at the end of clusters storing them, so we added a 'resident file' feature to use it up for data for small files.  (Yes, this is a guess:).

Comment: @AndrewMedico which raises the question why a 1 byte file is still reported as 4k.

Comment: Probably because Explorer doesn't actually know whether the filesystem was able to store the data resident or not (the MFT entry might have already been filled up with a very long name or other streams) - so it keeps things simple and just says every file occupies at least one cluster.

Comment: Thanks all answering quiet fast. As my question suggests, I'm fairly new in this area, I was wondering if possible to change cluster size programmatically with C++, but based on your responds, it looks it's not possible. However, I tried that "creative possibility"! that it looks might satisfy my requirement, and it's a generous respond, Thanks again @ths. 

However,although I will test it programmatically that what size would be for 100000 empty files with 30 character file names, but it looks for few of them in a folder the size of folder is ZERO, how it's possible?

Comment: i suspect that's bogus info from explorer. as andrew said, anything small will be in the mft anyway, and a directory entry is 4k big, even if explorer says zero. so this method won't actually help.

Comment: @ths: Cluster size is a term coined by FAT. On the disk level there's no such think as a cluster size. Mass storage devices are organized in blocks, and up to a few years ago the default block size was 512 Bytes (also called a sector then). These days jumbo-blocks are getting popular (block sizes between 2k to 8k, the most common 4k).

Comment: lieber @datenwolf, microsoft begs to differ, eg. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/140365/en-us "block" isn't a term anyway, what you are talking about may be "sector" and they exist exactly in 512 byte and 4k varieties.

Comment: @ths: Microsoft is not the center of wisdom and doesn't make the definitions; they'd like to, but they don't. Please expand your horizon: Other operating systems and file systems which organize filesystems in entirely different ways. For example Extents (JFS, XFS) or with a pool abstraction between filesystem and disk (ZFS). When it comes to low level disk access with current technology there are only *blocks*, addressed in a linear address space. This is called LBA (you may have seen this in the BIOS or EFI Setup) which stands for (drumroll) *Logical Block Addressing*. See the ATA comm specs.

Comment: @ths: Yes blocks are often called sectors on disk, but the term usually goes synonymous. See http://www.seagate.com/support/disc/manuals/ata/d1153r17.pdf and http://www.seagate.com/staticfiles/support/disc/manuals/scsi/100293068a.pdf

Comment: @datenwolf which is not really relevant since the OP probably doesn't want to address the physical disk blocks, but interacts with a file system.

Comment: @ths: Exactly. And depending on which filesystem OP uses the smallest possible allocation size for a single file may be much smaller than a single disk block/sector. For example it may be trivial to divide a 512 block recursively down to a certain level, from which small files could be allocated. I.e. 512 = 256 + 256 = 256 + 128 + 128 = 256 + 128 + 64 + 64 = 256 + 128 + 64 + 32 + 32. A filesystem optimized for working with very small files could do exactly that.

Comment: @ths: And there's more: Linux allows one to implement file systems as daemon programs (FUSE); I'd be trivial to implement a FUSE daemon that on the backside uses, say a SQLite3 DB and presents files to the font side. And given that you no longer have something as a minimum file size allocation limit (other than the metadata overhead of SQLite3). Guess what: Such a FUSE daemon exists: http://www.nongnu.org/libsqlfs/ –– **TL;DR:** *OP asked about minimum file size allocation and got a lot of wrong and misleading information. People are circlejerking about Clusters which are totally irrelevant.*

Answer (score 4):

Most file systems allocate disk space to files in chunks.  It is not possible to take less than one chunk, except for possibly a zero-length file.

Google 'Cluster size'

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using some indexed file library like [gdbm](http://www.gnu.org.ua/software/gdbm/): it is associating to arbitrary key some arbitrary data. You won't spend a file for each association (only a single file for all of them).

You should reconsider your opposition to "databases". [Sqlite](http://sqlite.org/) is a *library* giving you SQL and database abilities. And there are [noSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) databases like [mongodb](http://mongodb.org)

Of course, all this is horribly operating system and file system specific (but `gdbm` and `sqlite` should work on many systems).

<sup>AFAIU, you can configure and use both `gdbm` and `sqlite` to be able to store millions of entries of a few dozen bytes each quite efficienty.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

on filesystems you have the same problem. the smallest allocate size is one data-node and also a i-node. For example in IBM JFS2 is the smallest blocksize 4k and you have a inode to allocate. The second problem is you will write many file in short time. It makes a performance problems, to write in short time many inodes.

Every write operation must jornaled and commit. Or you us a old not jornaled filesystem.

A Idear is, grep many of your data recorders put a separator between them and write 200-1000 in one file.

for example:

```
0102030400506070809101112131415;;0102030400506070809101112131415;;...
```

you can index dem with the file name. Sequence numbers or so ....