# save a sequence of bits into a binary file (not in 8-bit format)

Tags: python, arrays, binary, bit

I have a sequence of bits for example `0101`, and I want to save this sequence to a file in binary format and while opening the saved file using a binary viewer, I need to show me exactly `0101` [I mean 4 bits]. but it showed me `00000000 00000001 00000000 00000001` [and this is 32 bits].
May I ask you to help me guys? Thanks

***My Code:***

```
f = open('my_file', 'w+b')
byte_arr = [0, 1, 0, 1]
binary_format = bytearray(byte_arr)
print(binary_format)
f.write(binary_format)
f.close()
```

***The Screenshot:***

[image: binary file]

Comment: Binary viewers are always going to show groups of 8 bits, that's just the way they work.

Comment: @MarkRansom Thank for you reply. You mean I can not save 0101 in a file?

Comment: There is no way to write only 4 bits to a file.  If you try, you'll get 8 bits anyway.

Comment: You might find the answers to [How to read bits from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10689748/how-to-read-bits-from-a-file) useful (esp [my own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10691412/355230) which also features a `BitWriter` class).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bit sequence `0101` then you can define that using a binary literal

```
>>> 0b0101
5  # in decimal
```

If you are starting from an array of bits, then you can use `int` with base 2

```
>>> byte_arr = [0, 1, 0, 1]
>>> int(''.join(str(i) for i in byte_arr), 2)
5
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I'm working on a compression algorithm (Huffman Coding) and I want to save 0101 in a file and while right clicking on the file and go to properties, it shows me the size of 4 bits. Is it possible?

Comment: You cannot have a file size of only 4 bits for [various reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002504/whats-the-smallest-possible-file-size-on-disk).